# This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.5 or newer

Tags: android-studio

This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.5 or newer.
but my android studio version is 3.3.1 and there is no new update from Google

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change Project level gradle as below -

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

Change gradle-wrapper.properties as below -

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Hope this will work...

Comment: Wow...! Worked for me...!

Comment: This helped me, when I moved to 3.6 canary build from 3.4.2. I reverted back using this solution. thanks.

Comment: Working for me. I have Android Studio 3.4, I update the classpath line to 3.4.2 instead of 3.3.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the classpath to the version of your Android Studio Version.
To Find Version :
Click on `help > About > Version` is visible.

It will download the Gradle according to your android studio version.

Eg :
If your android studio version is 3.3.2 then change as follow :
classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to lower your gradle version in your project `build.gradle` file.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Please make your answer more specific! This would help the OP to clarify...